# C++ Recursive Boolean Palindrome(string s)

Tags: c++, function, recursion, boolean, palindrome

For computer science class, we are getting into recursive functions, which I personally don't like, but we need to use it. The following code is intended to check if the string input 's' is palindrome.

```
bool palindrome(string s)
{
int len = s.length();
char start = s.at(0);
char last = s.at(0);

if(len>1)
{
    last = s.at(len);
}

if(start == last && len<=2)
{
    return true;
}
else if(start != last)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    s = s.substr(1, s.size() - 2);
    return palindrome(s);
}
}
```

After running this, and inputting a string, I get a runtime error 'std::out_of_range', and I'm not sure where I'm screwing up. I'm very new to recursive functions and c++ in general, so any help would be fantastic.

If any additional info is needed which I didn't provide please tell me.

*NOTE: We need to use a bool function and can only call in the string which we input into the function.

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion. `last = s.at(len);`: if s has 5 characters, len is 5, but, of course `s.at(5)` will barf at you, because it doesn't exist. Recursion is the least of your problems. You need to get some fundamentals of 0-based array indexing right.

Comment: Have this in mind: **ERRORS WERE MADE TO BE READ**.
You error contains the line where this error occurs, if not, run using the debug tool that will show you this.

Out of range error is thrown when you try to access an position in an array/string that don't exists (Less then zero or greater then size).
Process your code manually, step by step, then probably you will find the error.

Comment: "we are getting into recursive functions, which I personally don't like" Some situations are almost impossible to being solved without recursive functions

Comment: In addition to what @EliasSoares said: from what I heard - all recursive algorithms can be rewritten as iterative ones, but it is more recursive algorithms are more intuitive in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last = s.at(len);`

should be

`last = s.at(len-1);`

Answer (score 0):

If a string has length `len`, then the positions of the characters in it will be 0..len-1, which is why `last = s.at(len)` causes the error you are getting.